# How is the backlight in a LCD monitor dispersed equally?

Tags: visible-light, light-emitting-diodes

How is the backlight in a LCD monitor dispersed equally?

I mean are there any layers that disperse the light?

Comment: This might get more responses in the Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange, maybe?

Comment: Thanks but I tried it doesn't seem anyone knows.

Comment: This is not electrically engineering, this is more like photo-engineering. There are several methods, a common one is a scattering sheet lit from the side (this is common with Hg high pressure lamp backlights).

Answer (score 1):

There is a diffusion panel located on top of an led array, it essentially is a wide flat fiber optic panel with small holes on the front (Screen side). The LEDs shine into the plate and spread throughout the plate via total internal reflection. When light hits the holes, it comes out.

[Random thesis paper describing the theory of operation of a LCD screen](http://www.sumitomo-chem.co.jp/english/rd/report/theses/docs/20070100_sv7.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

In older LCDs with cold-cathode fluorescent lamp (CCFL) which runs along one side of display panel they also use special optical elements to distribute light evenly. Example is given here: http://www.zemax.com/support/resource-center/knowledgebase/how-to-model-an-lcd-backlight